# itextsharp html to pdf creates no borders

Tags: c#, html, border, itext

I use iTextSharp (on SharePoint but I hope this does not matter) to convert a HTML document to PDF. So far I was unable to get any borders around elements. How do I do this? Is this not supported?

Things I tried:

```
  // in c# code
StyleSheet styles = new iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.StyleSheet();
styles.LoadStyle("borderCls", "border-style", "solid"); // <td class="borderCls">
styles.LoadStyle("borderCls", "border-width", "1px");
styles.LoadStyle("borderCls", "border-color", "#000");
  //
styles.LoadStyle("borderCls", "border", "solid 1px #000");

  // in html
<td style="border:solid 1px #000">
  //
<td border="1">
  //
<td style="border-style:solid;border-width:1px">
```

But these did not work. I just can't get iTextSharp to create any borders.

**Update**: Also is it possible just to define a Border on only one specific side?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use this code.

```
<table border="1">
```

sure its woirking.
but solid and px is not working in html to pdf.

Comment: Thank you, this one finally gives me a Border. But it is not possible to just define a border on one specific side? I would like that not the whole table and every cell has a border.

Comment: if u want border for perticular cell so use pdfpcell and html convert in Ielement.

Comment: But it is not possible to use something like `border-bottom:1px` for a div? I didn't want to use tables at all at first...

Comment: **border-bottom:1px** use table instead of div both structure are same.if you are using table do easy to create pdf.

Comment: you can use like also:
cell.Border = PdfCell.BOTTOM_BORDER | PdfCell.TOP_BORDER | PdfPCell.LEFT_BORDER | PdfPCell.RIGHT_BORDER;

Comment: border-bottom (or any css border style) do not work @ManishSharma. Also I cannot use cell.Border as I do not have cells. I convert/create the PDF directly from HTML. Or is it possible to find a specific cell in this created document and modify it?

Answer (score 1):

you can play with table borders and have some examples here: http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/

XMLWorker CSS and HTMLsupport documentation http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/itextdoc/index.html

If you want to set only the left border in a table using only css, use the code below:

```
td.black-left-border {
    border: 0;    /*First set all the borders to 0, then set the desired borders width*/
    border-color: black;
    border-left-width: 1px; /*PDF*/
    border-left-style: solid;
}
```

you can also set the borders with different colors:

```
td.black-left-border-blue-bottom-border {
    border: 0;    
    border-left-color: black;
    border-bottom-color: blue; 
    border-left-width: 1px; 
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
}
```

Maybe the browser won't apply these styles but iTextSharp will. As you can see, you must be very specific in the css properties.